# господа вопрос о правильности моего подхода

Tags: python, tkinter, arduino

пишу редактор сценариев для сервоприводов под управлением ардуино на Питоне + ткинтер.

Задумка такая что вводишь градусы для сервоприводов он сохраняет в гдето (сначала думал насчет txt потом переключился на sql) и это все воспроизводит по времени.

Значения сохраняемые в базе данных каким то образом должны сравниваться со счетчиком времени и подхватывать значения из БД. Как это реализовать?

Comment: "...господа вопрос о правильности моего подхода...", ИМХО, я бы начал с того, что изложил суть встреченных трудностей на правильном и простом русском языке, без излишних "вывертов", отвлекающих от постижения сути.

Comment: Не важно как и где вы это сделаете. Начните с просто txt для начала.

Comment: встреченная трудность в данный момент прокинуть значения сохраненые в бд по времени, на сервопривода то есть: написать цикл сравнивания значений времени, если оно совпадает прокидывать на привода градусы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для всякой системы, управляемой от ЭВМ, должно выполняться ограничение на скорость протекающих в ней процессов (полоса пропускания системы F) и соответственно существует постоянный шаг дискретизации dt=(1/2F), в течении которого нужно генерировать неизменное внутри цикла управляющее воздействие U(T0+dt*k), где к номер управляющего цикла, T0 начальный момент времени.

В Вашем случае (управление по заданной программе) T0 известно, и можно принять T0=0. Управляющая программа записывается в таблицу (назовем ее U_Table) базы данных с колонками (k, U), где к - номер отсчета ( 0 <= k< N), N - число строк в Вашей таблице-длина циклограммы). Соответственно для реализации всего этого Вам нужен таймер, в котором с шагом дискретизации dt будет выполняться следующее (извиняюсь, но очевидные действия я напишу на псевдокоде - питон не мой язык):

```
//Формируете новый отсчет
k=k+1;
if(k>=N) k=0;

//Получаете из базы по отсчету k управляющее воздействие
U = ExecScalarSQL("select U from U_Table where k="+IntToString(k));

//Прокидываете управление U на сервопривод
out(U);
```

Я думаю, что обобщение этой схемы на случай произвольного числа приводов, не вызывает у Вас вопросов. В этом случае в U_Table нужно добавить колонку с идентификатором привода и в запросе по таймеру использовать его в Select.

Еще не большое добавление. Бывают ситуации, когда для управления системой в целом нужен маленький шаг квантования dt, но для некоторых каналов управления U(T0+dt*k) не меняется в течении достаточно длинных интервалов k. Очевидно, что в этом случае возможна некоторая оптимизация, если в U_Table хранить не отсчет k, а интервалы k, в течении которого U(T0+dt*k) остается постоянным. Соответственно U_Table будет состоять из колонок (k1, k2, U), где k1 и k2 начало и конец интервалов. Соответственно запрос к базе на извлечения управления будет выглядеть так:

```
select U from U_Table where k >= k1 and k <=K2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Если знаешь конкретно время на котрое нужно запускать, то можно использовать https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html

Можно использовать time.sleep() А затем делать запрос в БД выбирать нужные события.
Если в БД есть время запуска собитыя, можно также 1 раз, например в 1 сек выбирать записи из БД и запускать с помощью schrduler